# What happened to Preview's "Markup.appex"?

Tags: macos, preview, plugins

There's a Markup app extension in Mojave--it's clearly installed, because I can use it. Where did it go, though? It used to be in `/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Plugins/` in past versions of macOS, but it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-clicking on the Markup extension in System Preferences > Extensions offers a "show in Finder" option, which yields:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/PlugIns/PlaceholderMarkUp.appex
```

Comment: Ah-ha! I had hoped as much, but I only tried in the "Photos Editing" category--it works in the "Finder" category. Thanks!

Comment: @andyvn22 I'm intrigued why you need it's location....?

Comment: I'm trying to develop an action extension that behaves similarly, but Xcode's "action extension with UI" template is giving me very different behavior, so I was hoping to glean some secrets from its Info.plist--and I did! It lists itself as a non-UI service--it must be opening its UI itself.